# OWC does not work with IE8

Tags: vbscript, internet-explorer-8

I have a web page that is generated with Access 2003 and uses Office Web Components. It worked fine with IE6 and IE7 but does not work anymore with IE8.
Here are more details. I create an MSODSC component and a WSH object to get my ConnectionString in the registry. Then the Dropdown Lists are fed by a request to the database.
It works perfect with IE6 and IE7, works locally with IE8 but if the page is served by IIS to IE8, the drop down lists are empty.
Can anyone help me ?
Thanks
Mactov

It was just a security issue. I had put my site in the confidence zone (according to the error message). I transfered it into intranet zone and it works perfect.

Comment: in IE8 have you tried turning compatibility view on?

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and then (after 2 days) accept it. That way if anyone else experiences the same problem it'll be easier for them to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved - actually almost solved it. The help message was explaining me to put my pages into the "confidence zone" (I don't the actual name in english) but it was not working anyways. I then took my pages to the "local intranet" zone and it worked good. It is just a matter of security.
May that help.
Mactov